# Visual Studio Online TFVC Source Control - Can't add solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, tfvc

I have never used VSO before, and decided today to try it out for a small project I have. I added the solution to VSO with no problem, however I realized I made a dumb mistake and added the solution to the root of TFS. This isn't what I wanted, I want to add multiple projects under different folders. So I deleted the files from TFS and started over. Now when I try to add the same solution to VSO it fails, and gives me this error message:

> A project DAFT.sln that you are attempting to add to source control
>   cannot be added because the item Publish-WebApplicationWebsite.ps1 is
>   already under source control at the selected location.

Bear in mind that I deleted this info and it no longer exists on VSO. I don't see the above file anywhere on VSO? What did I screw up now?

Comment: is daft.sln still "bound"

Comment: No. I went into File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Source Control and made sure that all projects in the solution are unbound.

Comment: What do you see in the solution explorer?

Comment: Nothing related to DAFT. I have a "Project" folder which is my root, and you'll see a folder called "Rival" which is another project, and "BuildProcessTemplates" which was auto-created for me. I'm trying to add my DAFT solution but for some reason, TFS thinks it's already there. Here is a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/Q5izOXQ4ZcD

Comment: One thought I had - I read something about deleting an account on VisualStudio.com - it says that while the account is deleted, it remains recoverable for up to 90 days (I think). I'm wondering if TFS somehow has a "placeholder" for DAFT stored, since it once existed (as the root folder) and even though it's not visibly there now, maybe there's some kind of placeholder gumming up the works?

Comment: Can you create a DAFT folder next to Rival and add your solution another code in there. Then right click under Rivel and select "add files". Pict your DAFT folder.